# Offered a new position but unknown about salary?

Tags: salary, job-change

I have been offered a new position at the same company within a same department. We had one to one meeting. I am not sure if my salary will be increased or not? They have made no statement about that.

From the meeting I was told after 6 months, I can decide to go back my previous role or stay in new role if thing goes well.

What the polite way to ask if my salary will be increased when I start a new role or after 6 months of new role?

Comment: Where is your job? Country might be interesting here, as in some juristications they might even decrease your salary while in others its very likely to be raised by given laws. Not that its required for answering "How to ask this politely" but it would give some background.

Comment: Remember : "If you don't ask, the answer is always No".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> What the polite way to ask if my salary will be increased when I start
>   a new role or after 6 months of new role?

Just ask.

It would be better if you had asked about this during your one-on-one meeting, but it's not too late.

Something like: "I just realized that I forgot to ask if this new position comes with a raise? If so, would that raise happen immediately or after 6 months? Thanks!"

Comment: +1, but I'd first advise deciding on how much of a raise, if any, you want in this new role. If you don't care, just go ahead and ask, if you decide you want (say) at least 5k extra, then prepare in advance to negotiate for that or stick with where you are.

Comment: I wouldn't even give them the "or in 6 months" option, because they'll obviously automatically gravitate to that. Just ask what the compensation is, straight up. As berry120 said, go into the conversation with well thought out expectations, and the preparation to negotiate and advocate for yourself effectively.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something not quite as direct as just asking whether you're getting a raise, you can ask "Are the salaries for the two positions the same?" That way, you're not asking specifically whether you're getting raise. You have "plausible deniability" that you're just checking that you're not getting a salary cut, and at the very least doesn't come across as you *expecting* a raise, just asking whether you will get one. There are other ways of being indirect, such as asking "How are the tax withholdings handled?" (Going by "now" being May, the standard way of withholding would be to calculate your tax as if you had been making that much the whole year, which will result in overwitholding, so if you don't want overwitholding, you'd want them to make adjustments for you. Even if they aren't willing to comply, their response will tell you whether they're planning on giving you a raise.)

Comment: The company can't "make adjustments" to tax withholding.  The IRS writes the rules and the company follows them.

Comment: The company can't "make adjustments" to tax withholding on its own, but you can [use the IRS withholding calculator](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/irs-withholding-calculator) and inform your company of the the number of allowances you want to claim based on the calculator's results, which is a good idea if your situation changes mid-year.